# Next-offline and WorkboxOpts: Error: "runtimeCaching" is not a supported parameter. How to enable "runtimeCaching" in next.config.js

Tags: next.js, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I'm just getting started with [next-offline](https://github.com/hanford/next-offline) and found the section regarding workbox integration and its recipes.

According to the docs:

> If you're new to workbox, I'd recommend reading this quick guide --
> anything inside of workboxOpts will be passed to
> workbox-webpack-plugin.
>
> Define a workboxOpts object in your next.config.js and it will gets
> passed to workbox-webpack-plugin. Workbox is what next-offline uses
> under the hood to generate the service worker, you can learn more
> about it here.

After digging around, I found this great [section](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin#which_plugin_to_use).

Essentially it gives a suggestion to use two different options:

[GenerateSW](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin#generatesw) or [InjectManifest](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin#injectmanifest)

I would like to use the InjectManifest, however when I try to implement that in my `next.config.js` file. I get this error:

```
"runtimeCaching" is not a supported parameter.
```

This is my next.config.js:

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withImages = require('next-images');
const optimizedImages = require('next-optimized-images');
const withOffline = require('next-offline');

module.exports = withOffline(
  withImages(
    optimizedImages(
      withCSS(
        withSass({
          // useFileSystemPublicRoutes: false,
          // generateSw: false, // this allows all your workboxOpts to be passed in injectManifest
          generateInDevMode: true,
          workboxOpts: {
            swDest: './service-worker.js', // this is the important part,
            exclude: [/.+error\.js$/, /\.map$/, /\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/],
            runtimeCaching: [
              {
                urlPattern: /\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/,
                handler: 'CacheFirst',
                options: {
                  cacheName: 'hillfinder-images'
                }
              },
              {
                urlPattern: /^https?.*/,
                handler: 'NetworkFirst',
                options: {
                  cacheName: 'hillfinder-https-calls',
                  networkTimeoutSeconds: 15,
                  expiration: {
                    maxEntries: 150,
                    maxAgeSeconds: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 // 1 month
                  },
                  cacheableResponse: {
                    statuses: [0, 200]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          dontAutoRegisterSw: false,
          env: {
            MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN: process.env.MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN,
            useFileSystemPublicRoutes: false
          },

          webpack(config, options) {
            config.module.rules.push({
              test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
              use: {
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                  limit: 100000,
                  target: 'serverless'
                }
              }
            });

            return config;
          }
        })
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Also when I check the `Application` pane, in devTools I see this:

[image]

You'll notice what appears to me a duplication of fields i.e. `https-calls` and `hillfinder-https-calls` and `images` and `hillfinder-images`.

I thought the `cacheName` field in the `options: {}` in each was allowing one to include a custom name?

Just wondering if anyone has had experience setting this up?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

(These comments apply to the basic Workbox build tools, not specifically to the `next-offline` wrapper, but I think they're still accurate.)

If you're using `InjectManifest` mode, the idea is that you write all of your service worker logic, using the underlying pieces of Workbox that you need, following a model that's similar to what's described in the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/get-started#using_workbox) guide. You should include a call to `precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST)` somewhere in your service worker, and then the `InjectManifest` build tool is responsible for swapping out `self.__WB_MANIFEST` with an array containing the list of URLs to precache, along with revision information for each URL.

The `runtimeCaching` parameter is not compatible with `InjectManifest`. It's a parameter that can be used in `GenerateSW` mode, in with the Workbox build tool creates an entire service worker for you (including runtime caching routes). The `GenerateSW` mode takes in a declarative configuration and spits out the code for  service worker based on that configuration. If that sounds good—if you'd just like to configure some build options and get a complete service worker as a result—then using `GenerateSW` is the right choice.